# How can I send an object array in a retrofit POST?

Tags: android, retrofit

The Server is expecting something like this :

```
special_array = [{param1 = "string1", param2 = "string2"}, {param1 = "string3", param2 = "string4"}];
```

Do I need to make my own converter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First create a callback interface like this and pass the whole Object class.

```
 @POST(URL)
 public void newObject(@Body YourObject object, Callback<Boolean> success);
```

Retrofit uses Gson to serialize and deserialize JSON by default. For Example, If your Object class looked like this:

```
public class YourObject {

@Expose
private String param1;
@Expose
private String param2;

/**
* 
* @return
* The param1
*/
public String getParam1() {
return param1;
}

/**
* 
* @param param1
* The param1
*/
public void setParam1(String param1) {
this.param1 = param1;
}

/**
* 
* @return
* The param2
*/
public String getParam2() {
return param2;
}

/**
* 
* @param param2
* The param2
*/
public void setParam2(String param2) {
this.param2 = param2;
}

}
```

Then Gson would automatically serialize into the following JSON,

```
[
    {
        "param1": "string1",
        "param2": "string2"
    },
    {
        "param1": "string3",
        "param2": "string4"
    }
]
```

And you are all done!

Comment: that's great, but what if `i have other params, beside the array of Object, can I still use @Body?

Comment: Yes you can. Just add any other parameter/attachment followed by a comma. e.g @POST(URL)
 public void newObject(@Body Object object,
                 @Part("content") String content, Callback<Boolean> success);

Comment: @Body parameters cannot be used with form or multi-part encoding.

Comment: naming your class Object, not the best of ideas.

Comment: also, the expected body is apparently a list of objects, not just an object

Answer (score 0):

I just had to construct a bigger more complex object that took into account both parameters, something like that:

```
ComplexRequestObject complexRequestObject = new ComplexRequestObject();
complexRequestObject.param1 = new SemiComplexObject[]{
    new SemiComplexObject("value1", "valued2")};
complexRequestObject.param2 = "value3";
```